# Software for Windows and/or Android that has built in dictionary when reading PDF's

Tags: software

Is there any type of pdf(possibly others) readers that can translate in real time and/or have dictionary access to look up unknown words?

E.g., if I want to read a book in Latin it would be nice if I could double tap a word(likely need OCR too) and it show the possible meaning. Also would be nice to select a sentence and see the translation. Anything is better than nothing.

The idea is to have it integrated so it is quick.